# why component is not destroyed under v-if

Tags: vue.js

I have very simple example. There are two divs each with v-if with same variable, one with true and one with false. There is component nested inside the each of the divs (same component).

What I see (from the console.log) is that even there is v-if, the component is not destroyed and created but rather reused.

Is this bug? feature? Because I was relying on them to be destroyed (the problem occur in some more complex component).

Thanks.

Html and javascript below, there is also jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ekeydar/p64ewLd1/3/

This is the html:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="show1=!show1">
    Toggle  
  </button>
  <div v-if="show1">
    <my-comp title="comp1"/>
  </div>
  <div v-if="!show1">
    <my-comp title="comp2"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
Vue.component('my-comp', {
    props: ['title'],
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  created: function() {
    console.log('my-comp.created title='+ this.title);
  },
  destroyed: function()  {
    console.log('my-comp.destroyed title='+ this.title);
  }
}),

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show1: true,
  },
})
```

Comment: I had a head scratching and eye popping moment here for the last 15 minutes observing this behaviour in my app. Then I decided to google for this symptom and got to this thread... IMHO the whole purpose of adding v-if (ng-if in angularjs) was to force component to be destroyed. But thanks to @t.dirks answer we know that that's not the case by default in Vue! :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is the intended functionality for Vue. In order to let Vue know that the component shouldn't be reused but instead destroyed and create a different component, add a `key` attribute to the components.

Example:

```html
<div v-if="show1">
    <my-comp title="comp1" key="somekeyhere"/>
</div>
<div v-else>
    <my-comp title="comp2" key="someotherkeyhere"/>
</div>
```

*Note that you could also put the `key` attribute to the `div`, but I think it's cleaner to add it on the component since the `div` itself can be reused without issues.*

Comment: Does the key need to keep changing though?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a little trick (or horrible hack if you like) if you want your component to always be destroyed when it is hidden (e.g. to save memory). Use `NaN` as the `key`. Since `NaN` is never equal to itself Vue will always think it is a different element.

```
  <div v-if="show1">
    <my-comp title="comp1" :key="NaN"/>
  </div>
  <div v-if="!show1">
    <my-comp title="comp2" :key="NaN"/>
  </div>
```

You need `:key=` rather than `key=` because otherwise the attribute will be a string with the value `"NaN"`.

Comment: Due to this, mounted hook is being executed infinitely.

Comment: What do you mean indefinitely? It will be executed every time `show1` changes but that's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @Timmmm exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The difference between `v-if` and `v-show` is just whether or not the element exists in the DOM, not whether or not it is created.  `v-if` removes it from the DOM when false, `v-show` just hides it.  The component however is not destroyed either way.

Comment: `v-if` actually destroy the component when it false